# Execute SQL only on certain day of the month

Tags: sql, perl

I am trying to execute a SQL statement based on the day of the month e.g "if today is the 25th then execute SQL, else say "Today is not a valid rundate".

Essentially I'm using `DBI` to connect and run some SQL before building some HTML to be automatically emailed out.

However, I'm getting syntax errors like the following:

> Syntax error at XXXXX, near ", else"
>   (might be a runaway multi-line {} string starting on line XX)
>   Missing right curly or square bracket at XXXXX at end of line.

I have read that you cannot directly embed an instruction inside an expression (which I believe I may be doing). The script worked fine without the day element and the `else` statement.

```
# Get the current day of the month (along with other date parts we can ignore)
my ( $sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst ) = localtime( time );

## Filter based on day of week

my $sql;

if ( $mday == 25 ) {
    $sql = qq{<MY SQL STATEMENT HERE>
}
else {
    say "Today is not a valid rundate";
}

## Prepare and execute the SQL

my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql ) or die "Failed to prepare SQL: " . $dbh->errstr;
$sth->execute() or die "Failed to execute SQL: " . $dbh->errstr;

## Start building the HTML output

my $html = qq{
<table style="width:100%"><thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
};

## Loop round each row in the result set, and add to the HTML output for each one.

my $count = 0;

while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ) {
    #
    # process rows

    $count++;

    #say Dumper $row;
    #say "$row->{col1}, $row->{col2}, $row->{col3}";
    $html .= qq|
    <tr>
        <td align="right">$count.</td>
        <td>$row->{col1}</td>
        <td>$row->{col2}<td>
        <td>$row->{col3}</td>
    </tr>
    |;
}

## Close the HTML

$html .= "</table>";

say "$count rows processed.";

$html .= "<h2>Report SQL</h2>The report was produced with the following SQL<p><pre>$sql</pre>";

## Send the mail
my $sender = new Mail::Sender();

$sender->Open( {
    from     => 'email1',
    to       => $maildest,
    subject  => $mailsubj,
    ctype    => "text/html",
    encoding => "quoted-printable",
    smtp     => "localhost"
} ) or die $Mail::Sender::Error, "\n";

$sender->SendEnc( $html );
$sender->Close();

$dbh->disconnect;
```

Comment: That's not a [mcve] so this could just be a transcription error, but you never closed the `qq` in the statement `$sql = qq{<MY SQL STATEMENT HERE>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method here is just to die immediately, e.g.:

```
die "Today is not a valid rundate\n" unless 25 == $mday;
```

The rest of your code doesn't change (assuming it's working already).  I would assume you don't want to send the email every day saying that it's not a valid rundate.

Personally, I wouldn't do this, and would just specify the day of month in the crontab entry, which allows me to easily change the day if needed.

Comment: Thanks very much this worked like a charm and I appreciate you being constructive.

Answer (score 2):

If the code you have shown is what you're running then it's pretty clear that the problem is you haven't closed the string `qq{<MY SQL STATEMENT HERE>`. You've used a similar contruct later on, so it looks like you know what it should look like

But it doesn't make sense, if the current day isn't the 25th, to just print a message and carry on anyway. You leave `$sql` undefined and then try to `prepare` and `execute` as if nothing had happened

You need to stop execution altogether, and you should write something like

```
if ( $mday != 25 ) {
    say "Today is not a valid rundate";
    exit;
}

my $sql = qq{<MY SQL STATEMENT HERE>};
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql ) or die "Failed to prepare SQL: " . $dbh->errstr;
$sth->execute() or die "Failed to execute SQL: " . $dbh->errstr;
```

Or you could use `die` instead of `say`, which avoids the need for `exit`

I would also say that you should keep your delimiters consistent. You're using a mixture of `qq` with braces or pipes, as well as ordinary double quotes `"..."` for no particular reason that I can see. Just select one of these and stick with it

You should also pay attention to any error messages you get. If you had looked at the line numbers in the error I bet you could have figured out the problem to yourself, but you replace them with `XXX` as if they are irrelevant and of no use at all

Comment: Thanks alot i appreciate the comments and i agree with the fact that i need to stop execution when the argument is not true but i was not completely sure how to construct that. Also, the reason i removed the line numbers was because i have removed the SQL as it was sensitive information which renders them rather useless. I should have highlighted the lines for you but i thought that "near ", else" made it obvious as its the only occurrence in the code. Thanks again

Comment: If you are *NIX, you could use a CRON job. That way the script can be set up to run whenever you like. You get huge flexibility in when they run & they are triggered automatically.

Comment: @DuncanCarr: The problem with cron jobs is that they can mysteriously stop running, and no one will notice for months. There's also no reason to assume that the program should be run *every* 25th of the month.

Comment: @GrantBrennan: Yes, it's the only occurrence in the code that you show. But, as you say, you've clearly removed a bunch of stuff from what you've shown us, including some `use` statements that could have been very useful and aren't sensitive at all, so as far as we know there could be a dozen more `else` lines that we can't see, and the line that appears to be the problem may well have just been hacked that way as part of sanitising your code.